# Finite double sum: Improve index transformation

Tags: summation, transformation

In order to prove a rather complicated binomial identity a small part of it implies a transformation of a double sum.

> The double sum and its transformation have the following shape:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{l}\sum_{j=\max\{1,k\}}^{\min\{l,k+c\}}1=\sum_{j=1}^{l}\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{j,c\}}1\qquad\qquad l\geq 1, c\geq 1
> \end{align*}

Here I do not want to take care of the terms which are to sum up. They are set to $1$ for the sake of simplicity. What matters is an efficient, short indextransformation showing that the identity is valid.

At the time I've found a rather long-winded solution. It is added as answer to this question. But in fact I would appreciate to find a more elegant way to prove this identity.

Comment: There is a more general method, which I included in an answer to a similar question in [ interchange summation signs of multi-summation][http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200836/some-questions-about-interchange-summation-signs-of-multi-summation/1200892#1200892]   I hope that it satisfies you.

Comment: @Elaqqad: I'm not sure, if this method is also applicable, when $\min,\max$ are involved. I've to check it in more detail. But your answer is despite that interesting and helpful in general. (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest argument is geometric. A sketch makes it evident that if $c\le\ell$, the lefthand side is the number of points of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ lying in the convex hull of the points $\langle 0,1\rangle$, $\langle 0,c\rangle$, $\langle 1,1\rangle$, $\langle \ell-c,\ell\rangle$, and $\langle\ell,\ell\rangle$. For $c\le j\le\ell$ the $j$-section has $c+1$ points, and for $1\le j<c$ it has $j+1$ points, so in general it has $\min\{j+1,c+1\}$ points. Clearly

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{j,c\}}1=\min\{j+1,c+1\}\;.$$

Here’s the sketch:

[image]

The colored regions contain the points in question. The orange region comprises the $j$-sections with $c+1$ points; the blue, the $j$-sections with $j+1$ points.

For $c>\ell$ the blue region expands to the top of the square.

Comment: @BrianMScott: Thanks for your quick support! I think I could use an answer in this direction in order to shorten some parts of a  paper. (+1)

Comment: @Markus: You’re welcome. I just realized that I didn’t actually cover the case $c>\ell$, in what I originally wrote, but it’s the easier case anyway.

Comment: I see and it's ok. In fact it's the approach which is the point in this case. Everything else can be managed by myself. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** It would be nice to provide a more elegant solution than my answer below.

> The following identity is valid for $l\geq 1, c\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{l}\sum_{j=\max\{1,k\}}^{\min\{l,k+c\}}1=\sum_{j=1}^{l}\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{j,c\}}1
> \end{align*}

In Order to prove this identity we consider two cases: $c<l$ and $c\geq l$.

> **Case $(c<l)$:**
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{l}&\sum_{j=\max\{1,k\}}^{\min\{l,k+c\}}1\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^c1+\sum_{k=1}^{l-c}\sum_{j=k}^{k+c}1+\sum_{k=l-c+1}^{l}\sum_{j=k}^{l}1\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^c1+\sum_{k=1}^{l-c}\sum_{j=0}^{c}1+\sum_{k=1}^{c}\sum_{j=k+l-c}^{l}1\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^c1+\sum_{k=1}^{l-c}\sum_{j=0}^{c}1+\sum_{j=l-c+1}^{l}\sum_{k=1}^{j-l+c}1\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^c1+\sum_{k=1}^{l-c}\sum_{j=0}^{c}1+\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{k=1}^{j}1\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{k=0}^{j}1+\sum_{k=1}^{l-c}\sum_{j=0}^{c}1\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{k=0}^{j}1+\sum_{k=c+1}^{l}\sum_{j=0}^{c}1\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{k=0}^{j}1+\sum_{j=c+1}^{l}\sum_{k=0}^{c}1\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{l}\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{j,c\}}1\\
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (1) we separate $k=0$ and split the sum according to $\min\{l,k+c\}$
- In (2) indextransfomation of $k$ in rightmost summand
- In (3) exchange of sums in rightmost summand
- In (4) indextransformation of $j$ in rightmost summand
- In (5) merge of left and right summand
- In (6) indextransformation of $k$ in right summand
- In (7) exchange of index names in right summand

> **Case $(c\geq l)$:**
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{l}&\sum_{j=\max\{1,k\}}^{\min\{l,k+c\}}1\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^l1+\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{j=k}^l1\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^l1+\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{j=l-k+1}^l1\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^l1+\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}1\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{j=0}^{k}1\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{l}\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{j,c\}}1\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}

**Comment:**

- In (1) we separate $k=0$
- In (2) change of order of summation of $j$ in right summand
- In (3) indextransformation of $j$ in right summand
- In (4) merge of summands